# Can I show that for any matrix A = ST, S & T Both symmetric and invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

In my linear algebra class, my professor gave us an exercise, which is the following.

If A is an nxn matrix over the complex, one can show that A = ST for S and T both invertible and symmetric.

I guess I can use Jordan Block, but I don't know the exact step.

Can someone help me?

Comment: It won't work for any $A$; since $S$ and $T$ are invertible, $A$ must also be:  $A^{-1} = (ST)^{-1} = T^{-1}S^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Every Jordan block can be factorized into two symmetric matrices, 3 by 3 for instance.
$$
\pmatrix{
&&\lambda \\
& \lambda &\\
\lambda&&
} \cdot
\pmatrix{
&&1\\
&1 &1\\
1&1&
}
$$

Now use the fact that conjugation of a symmetric matrix is still symmetric.

Moreover, if $A$ is nonsingular, then so are $S$ and $T$.